# Trouble creating multiple modals

Tags: javascript, html, css, allow-modals

I've been working on a professional website that will include a portfolio section. I want the portfolio to contain several thumbnails--when each thumbnail is clicked on, a modal should open with more information about that subject. The problem I'm running into is that only the first modal opens. The second one doesn't work (and I'd like to add several of these ideally). I've been reading online help for months now and trying different solutions. Nothing has worked so far. I'll post the code here. Apologies for the length, the blocky colors, and the lack of images in this version. But I think you get the idea. Click on the buttons marked "Users conducting a card sort" to see the issue I'm having. Any help is appreciated!

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementsByClassName("modal")[0];

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementsByClassName("button")[0];

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}



// Cache selectors
var lastId,
    topMenu = $("#nav-links"),
    topMenuHeight = topMenu.outerHeight()+15,
    // All list items
    menuItems = topMenu.find("a"),
    // Anchors corresponding to menu items
    scrollItems = menuItems.map(function(){
      var item = $($(this).attr("href"));
      if (item.length) { return item; }
    });

// Bind click handler to menu items
// so we can get a fancy scroll animation
menuItems.click(function(e){
  var href = $(this).attr("href"),
      offsetTop = href === "#" ? 0 : $(href).offset().top-topMenuHeight+1;
  $('html, body').stop().animate({ 
      scrollTop: offsetTop
  }, 300);
  e.preventDefault();
});

// Bind to scroll
$(window).scroll(highlightNav);

$(window).ready(highlightNav);

function highlightNav(){
   // Get container scroll position
   var fromTop = $(this).scrollTop()+topMenuHeight;
   
   // Get id of current scroll item
   var cur = scrollItems.map(function(){
     if ($(this).offset().top < fromTop)
       return this;
   });
   // Get the id of the current element
   cur = cur[cur.length-1];
   var id = cur && cur.length ? cur[0].id : "";
   
   if (lastId !== id) {
       lastId = id;
       // Set/remove active class
       menuItems
         .parent().removeClass("active")
         .end().filter("[href='#"+id+"']").parent().addClass("active");
   }                   
}
```

```css
*{
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}


@media screen and (prefers-reduced-motion: reduce) {
 html {
  scroll-behavior: auto;
 }
}

#logo {
 max-width: 10%;
 height: auto;
 padding: 1vh;
}

nav {
 display: flex;
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 1; /* Stay on top */
   top: 0; /* Stay at the top */
 justify-content: space-around;
 align-items: center;
 min-height: 15%;
 background-color: grey;
 font-family: 'Red Hat Display', sans-serif;
}

.navname {
 color: #ECEAEA;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 letter-spacing: 0.4vw;
 font-size: 2.2vw;
 font-family: 'Volkhov', serif;
}

#nav-links {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-around;
 width: 38%;
 
}

#nav-links li {
 list-style: none;
}

#nav-links a {
 color: #ECEAEA;
 text-decoration: none;s
 font-weight: bold;
 letter-spacing: 0.2vh;
 font-size: 1.2vw;
 -webkit-transition: 50ms all ease-out;
    -moz-transition: 50ms all ease-out;
    transition: 50ms all ease-out;
}

#nav-links li.active a {
    color: #EADA15;
}
#mainpage {
 padding-left: 1vh;
 background-color: #EADA15;
 padding-top: 1%
}

#about {
 padding-top: 14%;
}

#portfolio, #experience, #education {
 padding-top: 12%
}
.column1 {
 width: 31%;
 float: left;
 margin: 1%;
}

.column2 {
 width: 64%;
 float: right;
 margin: 1%;
}

#portrait {
 max-width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 padding: 0vh;
}

.bodytext {
 font-family: 'Red Hat Text', sans-serif;
 font-size: 1.5vw;
 line-height: 2vw;
 text-align: justify;
 vertical-align: middle;
}
.divider {
 width: 100%;
 overflow: auto;
}

.column3, .column4, .column5 {
 width: 29%;
 float: left;
 margin: 1%;
}

#portfolio {
 background-color: blue;
 overflow: auto;
}

button {
 background-color: blue;
 border: none;
}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
  -webkit-transition: all 3s;
  -moz-transition: all 3s;
  transition: all 3s;
}

/* Modal Content/Box */
.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: 10% auto; /* 15% from the top and centered */
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 60%; /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */\
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: #aaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.portfolioimage {
 cursor: pointer;
 -webkit-filter: brightness(100%);
}
    

.portfolioimage:hover {
    -webkit-filter: brightness(70%);
    -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease;
    -moz-transition: all 500ms ease;
    -o-transition: all 500ms ease;
    -ms-transition: all 500ms ease;
    transition: all 500ms ease;
}

@media screen and (max-width:1024px){
 .nav-links a {
  font-size: 1.5vw;
 }
}

@media screen and (max-width:768px){
 nav {
 min-height: 20vh;
 }
 
 #logo {
 max-width: 15%;
 height: auto;
 padding: 1vh;
 } 
 
 .navname {
  font-size: 3vh;
 }
 
 .nav-links{
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  width: 15%   
 }
 
 .nav-links li {
  line-height: 4vh;
 }
 
 .nav-links a {
  font-size: 2vh;
  padding: 0.5vh;
 }
 
 #about {
  padding-top: 11vh;
 }
 
 .bodytext {
 font-size: 2.5vw;
 line-height: 3vw;
 text-align: left;

}
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
 position: relative;
 animation-name: animatetop;
 animation-duration: 1.4s
}

/* Add Animation */
@keyframes animatetop {
 from {top: -500px; opacity: 0}
 to {top: 0; opacity: 1}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
 
    <title>Adam McBride-Smith</title>
</head>
<body>
 <nav>
  <img id="logo" src="logo.png" alt="A magipie sits on an wire-rimmed AMS."/>
  <div class="navname">
   <h1>Adam McBride-Smith</h1>
  </div>
  <ul id="nav-links">
   <li>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="#experience">Experience</a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="#education">Education</a>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </nav>
 
 <div id="mainpage">
  <div id="about"> 
   <div class="about column1">
    <h4 id="bio" class="bodytext">I'm a technical communicator with a background in education and a passion for creative problem solving. Whether conducting user research, designing accessible interfaces, drafting flow diagrams, or writing documentation, I believe that collective efforts often produce the best results, and that technology can help show the way to a more open, compassionate, and democratic future. </h4>
   </div>
   <div class="about column2">
    <img id="portrait" src="portrait.jpg" alt="A picture of Adam smiling and wearing headphones"/>
   </div>
   <div id="div1" class="divider"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="portfolio">
   <h4>Portfolio</h4><br />
   <div class="portfolio column3">
    <div id="firstModal">
    <!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
    <button id="myBtn1" class="button"><img id="cardsortthumb" class="portfolioimage" src="cardsort.png" alt="Users conducting a card sort" width="100%" height="auto" /></button>

    <!-- The Modal -->
    <div id="myModal1" class="modal">

      <!-- Modal content -->
      <div class="modal-content">
     <span class="close">&times;</span>
     <h2>Web Page Usability Testing</h2><br />
       <h3>Competencies: Usability Testing, Data Analysis, Content Management<br />
        Personal Characteristics: Collaboration, Critical Thinking<br />
      Tools: MS Excel</h3><br />
        <p>As a project for a class on research methods at Portland State University, I participated in exploratory usability testing of a web page. The page was designed to help students and faculty in the Professional and Technical Writing Program get answers to their questions about the program. The purpose of the study was to determine whether the information categories used by the page aligned with user preferences.</p><br />
       <img id="cardsortfull" src="cardsort.png" alt="Users conducting a card sort" width="100%" height="auto" /><br /><br />
      <p>We started our research by conducting both open and closed <strong>card sorts</strong>. During our closed card sort, printed category cards that matched the actual site menu were distributed among the groups of users. Subcategory cards were also distributed. Our test participants then grouped the subcategory cards under their preferred headings. Data from each card sort was collected and collated to show the user preferences of the group as a whole.
         </p><br />
        <img id="simmat" src="simmat.jpg" alt="An Excell spreadsheet showing a similarity matrix" width="100%" height="auto" /><br />
        <p>Following the card sorts, I participated in creating a <strong>similarity matrix</strong> to describe the groupings preferred by our card sort participants, and to compare those preferences with the actual information design of the MPTW web page. We were able to highlight areas where the site aligned with user expectations, but also important areas where it was not aligned. Analyzing our data against the actual site brought to light some of the idiosycrasies that can result when legacy content is updated with more recent content, such as information “islands,” and inconsistent formatting. At the conclusion of our study, we compiled our findings and presented them to the head of the MPTW program.</p>
        <br />
   </div>
   </div>
   </div>
   </div>
   <div class="portfolio column4">
    <div id="secondModal">
    <!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
    <button id="myBtn2" class="button"><img id="personathumb" class="portfolioimage" src="persona2.jpg" alt="Users conducting a card sort" width="100%" height="auto" /></button>

    <!-- The Modal -->
    <div id="myModal2" class="modal">

      <!-- Modal content -->
      <div class="modal-content">
     <span class="close">&times;</span>
     <h2>Web Page Usability Testing</h2><br />
       <h3>Competencies: Usability Testing, Data Analysis, Content Management<br />
        Personal Characteristics: Collaboration, Critical Thinking<br />
      Tools: MS Excel</h3><br />
        <p>As a project for a class on research methods at Portland State University, I participated in exploratory usability testing of a web page. The page was designed to help students and faculty in the Professional and Technical Writing Program get answers to their questions about the program. The purpose of the study was to determine whether the information categories used by the page aligned with user preferences.</p><br />
       <img id="persona1" src="persona1.jpg" alt="Users conducting a card sort" width="100%" height="auto" /><br /><br />
      <p>We started our research by conducting both open and closed <strong>card sorts</strong>. During our closed card sort, printed category cards that matched the actual site menu were distributed among the groups of users. Subcategory cards were also distributed. Our test participants then grouped the subcategory cards under their preferred headings. Data from each card sort was collected and collated to show the user preferences of the group as a whole.
         </p><br />
        <img id="persona2" src="persona2.jpg" alt="An Excell spreadsheet showing a similarity matrix" width="100%" height="auto" /><br />
        <p>Following the card sorts, I participated in creating a <strong>similarity matrix</strong> to describe the groupings preferred by our card sort participants, and to compare those preferences with the actual information design of the MPTW web page. We were able to highlight areas where the site aligned with user expectations, but also important areas where it was not aligned. Analyzing our data against the actual site brought to light some of the idiosycrasies that can result when legacy content is updated with more recent content, such as information “islands,” and inconsistent formatting. At the conclusion of our study, we compiled our findings and presented them to the head of the MPTW program.</p>
        <br />
   </div>
   </div>
   </div>
   </div>
   <div class="portfolio column5">
    <h4>#</h4><br />
    <h4>#</h4><br />
    <h4>#</h4><br />
    <h4>#</h4><br />
    <h4>#</h4><br />
    <h4>#</h4><br />
    <h4>#</h4><br />
    <h4>#</h4><br />
   </div>
  </div>
  <div id="div2" class="divider"></div>
  <div id="experience">
   <h4>Experience</h4><br />
   <h4>#</h4><br />
   <h4>#</h4><br />
   <h4>#</h4><br />
   <h4>#</h4><br />
   <h4>#</h4><br />
   <h4>#</h4><br />
   <h4>#</h4><br />
   <h4>#</h4><br />
   <h4>#</h4><br />
   <h4>#</h4><br />
   <h4>#</h4><br />
   <h4>#</h4><br />
   <h4>#</h4><br />
   <h4>#</h4><br />
   <h4>#</h4><br />
   <h4>#</h4><br />
  </div>
  <div id="education">
   <h4>Education</h4><br />
   <h4>#</h4><br />
   <h4>#</h4><br />
   <h4>#</h4><br />
   <h4>#</h4><br />
   <h4>#</h4><br />
   <h4>#</h4><br />
   <h4>#</h4><br />
   <h4>#</h4><br />
   <h4>#</h4><br />
   <h4>#</h4><br />
   <h4>#</h4><br />
   <h4>#</h4><br />
   <h4>#</h4><br />
   <h4>#</h4><br />
   <h4>#</h4><br />
   <h4>#</h4><br />
   <h4>#</h4><br />
   <h4>#</h4><br />
   <h4>#</h4><br />
   <h4>#</h4><br />
  </div>
 </div>   
 <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Did you detect any errors and tried to debug you solution?

Answer (score 1):

`var btn = document.getElementsByClassName("button")[0];` this line mentions only to select the first element(`[0]`) from the list, that is why it only works for first element.

```
var btn = document.getElementsByClassName("button")[0];

btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}
```

This part of your code explicitly selects the first button and adds an event listener to it. Instead write it like this.

```
var btn = document.getElementsByClassName("button");
btn.forEach((b,i)=>{
  b.onclick = function() {
    modal[i].style.display = "block";
  }
})
```

also do the same if you have multiple modals.

Comment: Greyface, that makes sense. I tried to implement this and now neither modal is working, although it's quite possible that I've done it incorrectly. I'm also getting a warning in Dreamweaver that there's an "unexpected token" in line 12.

Comment: // Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementsByClassName("modal");

// Get the button
var btn = document.getElementsByClassName("button");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal

var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close");

// When the user clicks on the button, open the modal 
btn.forEach(b=>{b.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}})

Comment: @A.McBride i made a mistake yes, i've corrected it now,  do the same for span(x) also as they're also multiple, but there maybe problems with the window.onclick function though.  and checkout https://codepen.com if you haven't it is great for doing quick web things, and feel free to msg me on telegram https://t.me/greyface_1

Answer (score 0):

@greyface, that makes sense. I tried to implement this and now neither modal is working, although it's quite possible that I've done it incorrectly. I'm also getting a warning in Dreamweaver that there's an "unexpected token" in line 12.

```
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementsByClassName("modal");

// Get the button
var btn = document.getElementsByClassName("button");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal

var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close");

// When the user clicks on the button, open the modal 
btn.forEach(b=>{b.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}})

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```